# exec and tee to the logfile: explain these bash commands

Tags: bash

I saw this at the top of my bash script file:

```
export LOGFILE=$LOGDIRECTORY/${SCRIPT_NAME}.log
exec > >(tee $LOGFILE)
exec 2>&1
```

What does it do? What are two exec processes doing here? I realize that keeping it like this, all the output of the execution of the script is piped to `$LOGFILE` but I wanted to understand from the perspective of the `exec` statements.

Comment: This could make it clear: http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-redirections-using-exec

Comment: You saw this at the top of _your_ bash script file? ;)

Comment: The two `exec` lines could perfectly well be just one (`exec > >(tee "$LOGFILE") 2>&1`).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In shells, `exec` does 1) file openings and redirections 2) actual `exec`ing (replacing the current process image with another process image).

These `exec`s are redirections.

First you redirect (`exec 1> >(tee $LOGFILE)`) the `stdout` descriptor (1) to a process substitution-generated pipe connected to a concurrently run `tee` process that has `$LOGFILE` as its first argument and then you redirect the `stderr` descriptor (2) to the same place as where descriptor `1` now points (the tee pipe).

Keeping in mind that filedescriptors get inherited, you've just made
all future `stdout` and `stderr` output go to the `tee` process, which writes it to `$LOGFILE` and to wherever filedescriptor 1 pointed to originally (probably your terminal).

---

**Note:**
The tee process outputs to the original stdout (=the original filedescriptor 1) because, as you can learn from /searching [bash(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) for *Simple Command Expansion* and *Process Substitution*, process substitution ( `>()` `<()` ) happens (along with other expansions) before redirections get executed, which means that the redirection in `exec 1> >(tee "$LOGFILE")` happens *after* `tee` has started, leaving `tee` with the same filedescriptor 1 that it inherited from the parent shell. (If it were the other way around, `tee` would be made to write to its own input, which might make it deadlock, depending on its IO pattern).