# Problem redirecting output to log file and console in bash script

Tags: bash, scripting, io-redirection

I have a shell script which sucessfully redirects all output to a log file and stdout (console) at the same time. However, when it exits it seems to wait for some user input from the keyboard (experimentally, any key seems to work)... So, I run the script, see the output, it exits and I have to hit e.g. the spacebar before the terminal prompt re-appears. Typing `echo $?` then gives the correct exit code.

The basics of the script are:

```
#!/bin/bash
LOG="./test.log"
rm -f $LOG
exec > >(tee $LOG) 2>&1
if [[ "$1" = "T" ]]; then
 echo "twas true..."
 exit 0
else
 echo "twas false..."
 exit 100
fi
```

Any help appreciated... not only do I not want to hit the spacebar but I would like to understand what is going on?

***Amendment***: it appears that I have to hit **enter** to get the terminal prompt back. From my limited experience using the *ps* command it would seem that my script has terminated and the *bash* shell is in the interruptible sleep state **S**. It would appear that maybe the terminal prompt output has been consumed or incorrectly redirected? I cannot see why...

Comment: "`> >`" looks wrong. Use "`>>`".

Comment: `exec >>(tee $LOG) 2>&1` gives a syntax error?

Comment: See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/403788/108618).

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your issue on my machine. I see that `$PS1` is printed  at the moment of `tee $LOG` execution, but not after script end. After execution of script the command prompt is empty, but you actually can type your next command and it will be executed.

That looks like Process substituion `>()` runs `tee` in background.
Then `exec` redirects all the output to that background process.
But `tee` from background is still printing its output to the terminal. You can see something like this if you run `syslog | tee&`

At the moment when all shell output came to background process `tee`, bash printed a command prompt `$PS1` meaning that you are already can enter new commands. And only after command prompt was printed, your `echo` command printed its output to background process `tee` and then `tee` printed it to the terminal.

It is as if you ran your whole script background

That's approximately how I see why your command prompt was not printed after whole script execution.
Like `echo "twas true..." | tee $LOG&`. Here `&` means "run preceding command in background".

Try the following code. It will do the same but without that issue.

```
#!/bin/bash
LOG="./test.log"
rm -f $LOG
{
    if [[ "$1" = "T" ]]; then
     echo "twas true..."
     exit 0
    else
     echo "twas false..."
     exit 100
    fi
} | tee $LOG 2>&1
```

Also. By default `tee` rewrites file so it looks like `rm -f $LOG` is not needed.

Comment: Here is more about `exec` and process substitution: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/285252/432155